# backbone.js - Refresh button loads raw JSON to Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js

When I hit the refresh button in Internet Explorer, my backbone.js application dumps the last JSON output it fetched to the screen. I am not using the router. I know there's a way to disable this  but I can't remember. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

My application already disables cache:

```
$.ajaxSetup cache: false
```

Also, I am performing a fetch() after the application initialises which is an anti-pattern according to the backbone docs:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch

Answer (score 0):

If you append .html to the url, IE8 will behave correctly. This indicates IE8 somehow does not send the right content type header.

The right approach is to bootstrap all your json collections on the initial page load as recommend on the Backbone.js website http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap